# Grails - Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object

Tags: exception, grails, groovy, null

I am getting an error when trying to append a book to a list of classes list of books. Any ideas as to why or what I could do to fix it?

```
        //For each book in a class...
        for (int k = 0; k < rows.size(); k++) {
            Book book = new Book()

            //Assign the values to a new book object
            book.id            = rows[k].getProperty("ISBN")
            book.title         = rows[k].getProperty("title")
            book.author        = rows[k].getProperty("author")
            book.required      = rows[k].getProperty("required_optional")
            book.purchaseType  = rows[k].getProperty("rental_purchase")
            //book.purchasePrice = rows[k].getProperty("purchase_price")
            //book.rentalPrice   = rows[k].getProperty("rental_fee")

            //Append the book to the books list object in the particular class
            classes[i].books[k + 1] << book
        }
```

Comment: In that code, either classes could be null, or classes[i].books could be null. Make sure they are not.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of accessing by `[]` use `getAt`, then the `?` Operator will work:

```
classes?.getAt(i)?.books?.getAt(k+1) << book
```

or

```
classes?.getAt(i)?.books[k+1] << book
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rows.each { row ->
  Book book = new Book(...)
  classes[i].books << book
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without the full code it's hard to know what happens. try this code, it will show you which value is null:

```
// first check if classes[i] is null, add error handling if it is
if (classes[i]!=null) {
    //For each book in a class...
    for (int k = 0; k < rows.size(); k++) {     
        def books = classes[i].books[k + 1]
        if (books!=null) {
            // you can set values directly here
            def row = rows[k]
            Book book = new Book(
                id: k.getProperty("ISBN"),
                title: k.getProperty("title")
                // ...
            )
            //Append the book to the books list object in the particular class
            books << book
        } else {
            println "books is null, do something clever"
        }
    }
} else {
    println "classes[i] is null, do something clever"
}
```

I didn't test it, and you can probably make it shorter with some groovy goodness. this is just to get you started

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what 'classes' is, but if its a list containing 'Book' you can just do

```
classes << book
```

OR

```
classes.add(book)
```